# pass variable to nodesjs to localhost

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

**I want to pass the variable "valor_dollar" into the server localhost or an file html. Actually I can not to look the variable the browser.**

```
const express = require ('express');
const cheerio = require ('cheerio')
const request = require ('request-promise')
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express();


app.get('/',(req,res) => {


    res.end(prova());
});

app.listen(3000);

function prova(){

axios.get('https://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04ASX').then((response) => {
  // Load the web page source code into a cheerio instance
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)

  // The pre.highlight.shell CSS selector matches all `pre` elements
  // that have both the `highlight` and `shell` class
  const urlElems = $('td.line.text')[0]

  const urlText = $(urlElems).text()

  let valor_dollar = Number(urlText.substring(4,7))

  console.log(valor_dollar)

})

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling res.end method directly without setting the body, the prova function returns undefined.

Instead you can modify your method like this to have a callback that runs after the HTTP call.

```js
function prova(callback){

axios.get('https://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04ASX').then((response) => {
  // Load the web page source code into a cheerio instance
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)

  // The pre.highlight.shell CSS selector matches all `pre` elements
  // that have both the `highlight` and `shell` class
  const urlElems = $('td.line.text')[0]

  const urlText = $(urlElems).text()

  let valor_dollar = Number(urlText.substring(4,7))
  callback(valor_dollar);

});

}
```

and the route should be like this:

```js
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
   prova(function(value) {
     res.body = { dollar_value: value };
     res.end();
   });
});
```